Forces in tangentially-accelerating circular motion
Let's say a car is moving along a semicircular path. It moves with constant speed for the first half. Then, it accelerates with constant tangential acceleration for the second half of the semicircle. In the frame of reference of the driver, what are the forces felt?
I'm not sure I understand if the centrifugal force will exist (for the driver) along with the centripetal, and if the centrifugal is also caused by friction when the car is accelerating. Are there both centrifugal AND friction fictitious forces during acceleration?

Did you mean to write "centrifugal" twice in bullet 1.?

Consider your experiment of a driver travelling in a circle.
Now when you make the free body diagram of the driver, you can notice that the only force acting on the horizontal direction is due to friction. Thus we can safely say that the driver is able to travel in the circle due to the help of friction which in turns gives him an acceleration towards the centre which is known as centripetal acceleration.
Centrifugal acceleration however is the acceleration felt by the driver when he is travelling in the circle. It is a pseudo force i.e it is fictitious. It is just a acceleration force felt by the driver when he is travelling in a circle. This is due to Newton's third law of motion, he should feel as much acceleration as he gives towards the centre.
Now your driver begins to accelerate the car. Again the only force in the horizontal direction is friction which is already busy in giving the car a centripetal acceleration. So how does he move? Is this due to some sort of power in the engine or what. The answer is no. The engine only provides a thrust which is facilitated by a component of friction which helps him to increase his speed as well as remain attached to the centre.
P.S Centrifugal force is not always due to friction, since friction is the only force in the horizontal direction, we used it.
You might be wondering why friction is helping the driver when it should have been decreasing it's speed. The answer is friction doesn't always tends to oppose motion. It tends to oppose relative motion.
Sorry for some mistyping... (This is my first answer) :D
